# .NET core build output contains a lot of DLL files

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have .NET Core solution with ~30 projects, and I don't get one thing - each project compiled Bin output is very huge. Basically it contains whole bunch of Microsoft.AspNetcore.* and System.* assemblies, which makes output about 15-30mb (even for really small projects).
The solution divided into smaller projects with purpose to make it less coupled, but now it makes more troubles than it helps - overall size of all compiled projects is around 700mb..

I agree that it would be OK for "startup"/"composite root" projects, where everything should be in one place, but now it looks like every project is "published", or like compiled as "standalone" and not using installed frameworks.

It's not a problem as such, but it makes the solution not so robust in terms of CI/CD, publishing artifacts, etc. Any ideas what might be wrong? Is it really as designed?

One possible reason is that for some historical reason my solution targets net461 (aka "full" .NET Framework). However I'm considering porting everything to netcoreapp1.x/netstandard. I tried to do it with some projects - and it looked like for "library" projects it copies only few assemblies, but for some other projects (e.g. tests written with xUnit) - there are still a lot of "framework-based" DLLs, that could be used from global cache or smth.. Even in net461 current situation is still a bit weird.

I also was trying to put all built artifacts into one folder on CI server, but there are other issues with it - like third-party libraries conflicts, when different version libraries in different projects are used. It's understandable for third-party libraries, but "framework" libraries could be "smarter"..

Just for reference, full list of assemblies being copied to Bin output:

```
Autofac.dll
Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll
AutoMapper.dll
FluentAssertions.Core.dll
FluentAssertions.dll
JetBrains.Annotations.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.Abstractions.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Cors.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Host.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching.Abstractions.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.dll
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll
Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Composite.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Globalization.CultureInfoCache.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.Abstractions.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders.dll
Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.dll
Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll
Newtonsoft.Json.dll
NLog.dll
NLog.Extensions.Logging.dll
NLog.Web.AspNetCore.dll
System.AppContext.dll
System.Buffers.dll
System.Collections.Immutable.dll
System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll
System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll
System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll
System.Console.dll
System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll
System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.dll
System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll
System.Globalization.Calendars.dll
System.IO.Compression.dll
System.IO.FileSystem.dll
System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll
System.Net.Http.dll
System.Net.Sockets.dll
System.Numerics.Vectors.dll
System.Reflection.Metadata.dll
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll
System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll
System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll
System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll
System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll
System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll
System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll
System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll
System.Threading.Thread.dll
System.ValueTuple.dll
System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll
System.Xml.XmlDocument.dll
System.Xml.XPath.dll
System.Xml.XPath.XDocument.dll
```

Comment: For 2.0, see the runtime store: https://github.com/dotnet/designs/issues/8

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Not exactly what could save me, since it's mainly for publishing/deployment as I understand, but still a good direction. Targeting `netcoreapp` probably is still the best idea if you want to get full benefits of new .NET and tooling. Targeting `net461` and others - seems like based on a lot of workarounds, and it kind of explains why they wanted to drop supporting it completely from .NET Core 2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems I found it myself.. There are `CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies` and `CopyNuGetImplementations` flags for .NET Core projects (i.e. new-style *.csproj files).

For .NET Core it's:

```
<!-- dependencies coming from the package manager lock file should not be copied locally for .NET Core and .NETStandard projects -->
<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies Condition="'$(CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies)' == ''">false</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
```

For .NET Framework it's set as "true" by some reason. Therefore binaries are so big in size.

Regarding xUnit projects - they are also overriding these flags and set them to true. Actually tests are working with having them "false" when you are using `dotnet xunit` or `dotnet test`, but it should be really "true" if you want to use `xUnit console runner`.

It doesn't really help me, but at least it explains why it happens..
It's really frustrating to have project just with one class, which is ~5kb, but Binary output is 16Mb.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similiar problem with a little .NET core console app targeting `net461` (which brought me here).

The `Microsoft.Packaging.Tools.Trimming` tool (now found [here](https://github.com/ericstj/Microsoft.Packaging.Tools.Trimming)) sort of did the job for me at the end, as most of the copied assemblies weren't used by my application anyway. Just install the [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Packaging.Tools.Trimming) and insert following lines in the project file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <TrimUnusedDependencies>true</TrimUnusedDependencies>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This will check for unused dependencies and remove them. Maybe that can reduce the number of DLL files a little.

Comment: Can you give us a relevant quote from the link you posted.  This way, if the link dies, your answer retains the relevant details.  Thank you!

Comment: @theUtherSide Sure, I added the minimal approach to use the tool which was enough in my case. Additional options are described  in the linked doc file.

Comment: "The method described here" is now a bad link

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/standard/commit/bf1e5a493419a95584c50f4b2b9b1ab6636a6617 explains where things went

Comment: The trimmer was relocated to https://github.com/ericstj/Microsoft.Packaging.Tools.Trimming

Comment: @ferventcoder Thanks for the info, I updated the link.

Comment: I also target net461, but adding the Trimming NuGet package and the TrimUnusedDependencies setting didn't seem to change anything for me. I still got 134 extra dlls in my build output.